# What does these statements mean?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
 int s[4][2]={
               {1,2},
               {3,4},
               {5,6},
               {7,8}
             };
int (*p)[2]; // what does this statement mean? (A)
int i,j,*pint;

for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
 p=&s[i];
 pint=(int*)p;  // what does this statement mean? (B)
 printf("\n");
  for(j=0;j<=1;j++) {
    printf("%d",*(pint+j));
  }
}
```

I cannot understand Statement 'A' and 'B' .How and what has been done? 
please explain this very clearly.

Comment: Tag homework questions please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement A is a declaration

```
int (*p)[2];
      ^      p is
int (*p)[2];
     ^       p is a pointer
int (*p)[2];
        ^    p is a pointer to an array
int (*p)[2];
         ^   p is a pointer to an array of 2
int (*p)[2];
^^^          p is a pointer to an array of 2 int
```

Statement B is an assignment expression with an embedded cast

```
pint=(int*)p;
           ^  take the value in p (of type "pointer to array of 2 ints")
pint=(int*)p;
     ^^^^^^   take the value in p, convert it to 'pointer to int'
              even if it doesn't make sense to do so
pint=(int*)p;
^^^^^         take the value in p, convert it to 'pointer to int'
              and put the resulting value (whatever that may be) in pint
```

Casts are bad. Avoid casts as much as possible.
<sup>(*) except in very particular circumstances like `<ctype.h>` or variadic functions or ...</sup>

Comment: @ pmg
`Casts are bad. Don't ever(*) use casts.` why?

Comment: @Meprogrammer: the compiler has a method for converting between values of different types. It's called 'implicit conversion'. When you cast, you effectively tell the compiler to **NOT DO** its job and leave the conversions to you. Very, very often, the compiler knows much better than the programmer what conversions are appropriate.

Comment: @ pmg i thought you stressed on `(*)` casts

Comment: No, no. I meant casts in general. They are bad whether they deal with pointers or not.

Comment: "Don't ever use casts, except that there are so many situations in which you should use casts that I can't even list them". I don't think this is useful advice. Perhaps, "prefer to avoid casts"? In this case, `pint = &((*p)[0]);` means "make `pint` point to the first element of the array pointed to by `p`", which is what is wanted.

Comment: Hmm ... compromise? :) @Steve: Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
int (*p)[2];
```

This means that `p` is a pointer to an array of 2 `int` values.

```
pint=(int*)p;
```

This means that `pint` is assigned the value of `p`. Since `p` is a pointer to an array of `int`s, this means that `pint` now points to the first `int` of that array.

**Update:**

To help you read C or C++ declarations (like statement A above) you can use these two rules:

1. Start from inside the parentheses, working your way outside
2. Read from the right going to the left

You can also use the online tool http://www.cdecl.org to help you while learning. Paste something into it and see what comes out.

**Second update:**

`(int*)` in the context of statement B is a [*cast*](http://www.aui.ma/personal/~O.Iraqi/csc1401/casting.htm).

Answer (score 2):

'A' declares a *pointer to an array of 2 elements*, or in other words, a pointer to `int[2]`.

'B' converts the *array pointer* into a pointer an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

A: `p` is a pointer to an array of 2 integers.
B: Well, just the line before B, `p` is now pointed to the beginning of `s`.
   And, at B, `pint` is assigned to point to the same place as `p`. So it can be use later on (2 lines later).

Hope this help.